# # of counts of an element - Combinatorial Proof of Inclusion-Exclusion Principle (IEP) [Ross P31]

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> Let $A_{1},\ A_{2}$, , $A_{n}$ be $n$ sets. Then $|A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup ... \cup A_{n}|=
> \sum_{i}|A_{i}|-\sum_{i<j}|A_{i}\cap A_{j}|+ \cdots + (-1)^{n-1}|A_{1}\cap A_{2}\cap\ \cap A_{n}|.
> $
>
> [Proof.](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/don/courses/math1904/lect09.pdf) Suppose that $x\in \bigcup_{1 \le h \le n} A_h $ is in 
>   exactly $m$ of the sets $A_{1}, A_{2}$, . . . $, A_{n}$. How many of the sets of the form $A_{i_{1}}\cap A_{i_{2}}\cap\cdots\cap A_{i_{k}}$ with $i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k$ is $x$ in? The answer is $\left(\begin{array}{l}
> m\\
> k
> \end{array}\right)$ because it is just the number of ways of choosing $k$ of the sets which contain $x$.
>
> $\color{red}{\blacklozenge}$ This means that on the right hand side of the formula, $x$ will be counted
>   $
> \left(\begin{array}{l}
> m\\
> 1
> \end{array}\right)\ -\ \left(\begin{array}{l}
> m\\
> 2
> \end{array}\right)\ +\cdots +(-1)^{m-1}\ \left(\begin{array}{l}
> m\\
> m
> \end{array}\right)
> $ times.

I espy why the IEP and the last line (after the red lozenge) are true for $m \le 3$ sets, thanks to pictures like [this one on page 2 of 7](http://onlinemathcircle.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/21-pie.pdf). Yet I don't perceive it when $m \ge 4$ (which I don't think can be visualised) ? Whence does this expression originate?

Answer (score 4):

You are right saying that no similar picture can be made with discs. However a set can be given any shape. Here's an example with four sets. 
[image: Intersections of four sets]

- $A$ green
- $B$ blue
- $C$ yellow
- $D$ red
- $A\cap B$ pink
- $A\cap C$ cyan
- $A\cap D$ dark brown
- $B\cap C$ light green
- $B\cap D$ violet
- $C\cap D$ orange
- $A\cap B\cap C$ red brown in the middle
- $A\cap B\cap D$ bright green
- $A\cap C\cap D$ light brown
- $B\cap C\cap D$ pale blue
- $A\cap B\cap C\cap D$ black

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to answer this question from *three different point of views*. Here's a quick overview: We start with focus at

> **1.)** The *essence* of IEP: Transformation of *at least* information to *exact* information
>
> **2.)** Analyse the red lozenge expression
>
> **3.)** Eye-birds view: The *essence* of IEP is just a *shift by one*
>
> **4.)** No more answers, but further questions

Now to the details:

> **1.)** The *essence* of IEP: Transformation of *at least* information to *exact* information:
>
> If counting objects having *at least* a number of properties is simple, but counting objects having *exactly* a number of properties is difficult, than the IEP comes into play.

In our example the *objects* are the elements contained in $A_1,\dots,A_n$ and the *properties* of an element $x$ are the sets $A_j,1\leq j\leq n$, which contain $x$.

If we have this *essence* of IEP in mind and we look at the expression:

\begin{align*}
\left|\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}A_j\right|=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left|A_j\right|
-\sum_{1\leq i \leq j \leq n}\left|A_i\cap A_j\right|\pm\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\left|\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}A_j\right|\tag{1}
\end{align*}

we observe, that the right hand side (RHS) consists of summands with *at least* information. Because e.g.

$$\left|A_i\cap A_j\right|\quad \text{in}\quad\sum_{1\leq i \leq j \leq n}\left|A_i\cap A_j\right|$$

counts not only the number of elements which are in $A_i$ and $A_j$ it counts more precisely the number of elements which are *at least* in $A_i$ and $A_j$, since elements $x$ in $A_i\cap A_j$ may also be contained in other sets of $A_1,\dots,A_n$.

Now, the LHS
$$\left|\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}A_j\right|$$
  shows the number of elements which are *exactly* in $\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}A_j$.

> **2.)** Analyse the red lozenge expression
>
> Keeping 1.) in mind we analyse the expression:
>   \begin{align*}
> 1 = \binom{m}{1}-\binom{m}{2}\pm\cdots+(-1)^{m-1}\binom{m}{m}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>   which results from looking at a specific element $x$ which is contained in exactly $m$ sets of $A_1,\dots,A_n$.

We start by looking at the RHS of $(2)$:

In $\binom{m}{1}$ the element $x$ is counted *once for each of the $m$ sets which contain $x$*.

Since these sets $A_j$ are not disjoint (they contain $x$), some elements are counted *more than once*. Those are the elements that belong to *at least* two of the sets $A_j$, or the intersection $A_i \cap A_j$. This is valid especially for the element $x$. We wish to consider every such intersection, so we subtract $\binom{m}{2}$.

When we subtract the sum of the number of elements in such pairwise intersections, some elements may have been subtracted *more than once*. Those are the elements that belong to *at least* three of the sets $A_j$ and one of them is $x$ (assuming $m\geq3$). So, we add the sum of the elements of intersections of the sets taken three at a time, resulting in subtracting $\binom{m}{3}$.

This process goes on with sums being alternately added or subtracted until we come to the last term - the intersection of all sets $A_j$.

These arguments are *for better insight only*. To see that the RHS  identity $(2)$ is clearly valid, we observe

\begin{align*}
\binom{m}{1}&-\binom{m}{2}\pm\cdots+(-1)^{m-1}\binom{m}{m}\\
=&\binom{m}{0}-\left(\binom{m}{0}-\binom{m}{1}+\binom{m}{2}\mp\cdots+(-1)^{m}\binom{m}{m}\right)\\
=&1-(1-1)^m\\
=&1
\end{align*}

Some more and alternative insight into the relationship between *exact* and *at least* information is provided in the next section.

> **3.)** Eye-birds view: The *essence* of IEP is just a *shift by one*
>
> It's remarkable, that from a higher point of view, namely when using generating functions this information is condensed and encoded by a simple *shift by one* in the arguments.
>
> *Note:* This *shift by one* provides a kind of *bird's-eye view* to the *alternating sum* of the IEP.

Let

- $\binom{m}{k}$ ... number of intersections of $k$ sets, each containing elements which are contained in exactly $m$ sets
- $e_m$ ... number of elements, which are in *exactly* $m$ sets
- $l_m$ ... number of elements, which are in *at least* $m$ sets

> Using this notation, the IEP (1) can now be written as:
>   \begin{align*}
> e_1+e_2+\cdots+e_n=l_1-l_2\pm\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}l_n
> \end{align*}

Observe, that
\begin{align*}
l_k=\sum_{m=k}^{n}\binom{m}{k}e_m\qquad\qquad0\leq k\leq n\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> We now introduce the *generating functions* $L(z)$ and $E(z)$ having $l_k$ and $e_k$ as coefficients:
>   \begin{align*}
> L(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}l_kz^k\qquad\qquad E(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}e_kz^k
> \end{align*}

According to $(3)$ we get:
\begin{align*}
L(z)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}l_kz^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{m=k}^{n}\binom{m}{k}e_mz^k\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{n}e_m\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}z^k\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{n}e_m(z+1)^m\\
&=E(z+1)
\end{align*}

> From this we conclude that
>
> $$E(z)=L(z-1)$$
>   *Note:* This is remarkable, since the wanted $e_m$ which are the coefficients of $z^m$ of $E(z)$ can be simply calculated by changing $z$ to $z-1$ in the equation $L(z)=E(z+1)$ of the corresponding generating functions.

The coefficients $e_m=[z^m]E(z)$ giving the number of elements which are in *exactly* $m$ sets can now be calculated from $L(z-1)$.

\begin{align*}
e_m&=[z^m]E(z)\\
&=[z^m]L(z-1)\\
&=[z^m]\sum_{k=0}^{n}l_k(z-1)^k\\
&=[z^m]\sum_{k=0}^{n}l_k\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}z^j(-1)^{k-j}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}l_k\binom{k}{m}(-1)^{k-m}\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^{n}(-1)^{k-m}\binom{k}{m}l_k
\end{align*}

> We summarise:
>   \begin{align*}
> L(z)=E(z+1)&\qquad\qquad\qquad l_k=\sum_{m=k}^{n}\binom{m}{k}e_m\\
> &\tag{4}\\
> E(z)=L(z-1)&\qquad\qquad\qquad e_k=\sum_{m=k}^{n}(-1)^{m-k}\binom{m}{k}l_m\\
> \end{align*}

*Note:* $l_k$ and $e_k$ form a so called *inverse relation pair*. So, the IEP can also be expressed in terms of this specific combinatorial identity. Many different inverse relation pairs can be found e.g. in *Combinatorial Identities* from John Riordan. The above pair is stated in *section 2.2: The simplest inverse relations*.

> *Summary*: From this generating functionological view and adapting H.S.Wilf (see section 4.2 from [Generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf)): This is the Sieve Method (IEP): The act of replacing the variable $z$ by $z-1$ in the generating function $L(z)$ replaces the *unfiltered* data $\{l_m\}$ by the *sieved* quantities $\{e_m\}$.

This interesting question from [LePressentiment](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/53259/lepressentiment) gives rise to ask if there are *further interesting principles* based upon other binomial inverse pairs which could be applied to boolean algebras.

> **4.)** No more answers, but further questions:
>
> **Question**: Are there further *inverse relation pairs* which can be interpreted in the *context of boolean algebras* and which provide an interesting *transformation of information* similar to the IEP's *at least* to *exact* transformation?
>
> Please, find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809247) the corresponding MSE question.

Answer (score 2):

No pictures are really needed, the left brain hemisphere can do this all by itself.

Let us see what the right hand side of your formula,
$$
\sum_i|A_{i}|-\sum_{i<j}|A_{i}\cap A_{j}|+\cdots +(-1)^{n-1}|A_{1}\cap A_{2}\cap\ldots \cap A_{n}|, \tag1
$$
counts exactly. Since the formula has signs, it will be a weighted enumeration with weights$~\pm1$. Each term in one of the summations is associated to a collection of summations variables $i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k$ which is completely determined by the set $I=\{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k\}$; thus summand is $|A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap\cdots\cap A_{i_k}|$, and it has sign $(-1)^{k-1}$. So the formula counts pairs $(I,x)$, where $I$ is any non-empty subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $x\in\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i$, with weight $(-1)^{|I|-1}$. Now rather than fixing $I$ first and then letting $x$ vary, one can fix $x$ first and then let $I$ vary (a standard double counting trick). Since we require $x\in A_i$ for all $i\in I$, once $x$ is fixed one might as well only consider those $A_i$ for which $x\in A_i$, so one can put $J_x=\{\, i\mid x\in A_i\,\}$, and the sets $I$ that one can take for the given$~x$ are precisely all the non-empty subsets of$~J_x$, and each such $I$ is counted with weight $(-1)^{|I|-1}$. Now if $m=|J_x|$, then the are $\binom m1$ singleton sets that can be chosen for$~I$, $\binom m2$ sets of size$~2$, and in general $\binom mk$ subsets of size$~k$. All in all the contribution to the counting for any fixed $x$ is
$$
  \binom m1-\binom m2+\binom m3-\cdots +(-1)^{m-1}\binom mm \tag2
$$
where $m=|J_x|$, as the cited text claims.

It is now of course easy to see that $(2)$ gives $1$ whenever $m>0$, while it gives $0$ when $m=0$, so summing over all $x$ gives $|A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_n|$, the left hand side of the original formula.