# Are there further transformation principles similar to the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle (IEP)?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, boolean-algebra, inclusion-exclusion

This question is motivated by the elaboration of the question [Combinatorial Proof of Inclusion-Exclusion Principle (IEP)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/749390).

Let's consider the following two aspects:

> 1.) IEP transforms *at least* information to *exact* information

Applying the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to $n$ sets $A_1,\dots,A_n$ gives:

\begin{align*}
\left|\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}A_j\right|=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left|A_j\right|
-\sum_{1\leq i \leq j \leq n}\left|A_i\cap A_j\right|\pm\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\left|\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}A_j\right|\tag{1}
\end{align*}

We observe that the LHS representing an *exact* information can be represented by the RHS providing an *at least* information.

> 2.) Generating functions and corresponding binomial inverse relation pairs

Let

- $e_m$ ... number of elements, which are in *exactly* $m$ sets
- $l_m$ ... number of elements, which are in *at least* $m$ sets

Using this notation, the IEP (1) can now be written as:
\begin{align*}
e_1+e_2+\cdots+e_n=l_1-l_2\pm\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}l_n
\end{align*}
We now introduce the *generating functions* $L(z)$ and $E(z)$ having $l_k$ and $e_k$ as coefficients:
\begin{align*}
L(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}l_kz^k\qquad\qquad E(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}e_kz^k
\end{align*}
We observe following relations (see e.g. the answer section of the question above)
\begin{align*}
L(z)=E(z+1)&\qquad\qquad\qquad l_k=\sum_{m=k}^{n}\binom{m}{k}e_m\\
E(z)=L(z-1)&\qquad\qquad\qquad e_k=\sum_{m=k}^{n}(-1)^{m-k}\binom{m}{k}l_m\\
\end{align*}

This gives rise to the following question:

> **Question**: Are there further *inverse relation pairs* which can be interpreted in the *context of boolean algebras* and which provide an interesting *transformation of information* similar to the IEPs *at least* to *exact* transformation.

Comment: Are you familiar with general Mobius inversion on posets?  It is a very useful generalization of property 1.

Comment: @JairTaylor: My knowledge on (general) Möbius inversions is far too little. Thanks for the hint! Very interesting! Good point for further studies. Best Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no one has answered this yet, I'll elaborate a little on my comment.

One way of phrasing the inclusion-exclusion principle is as follows.  Here I will borrow the notation from Richard Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics Vol. 1, which is freely available on Stanley's web site.  Let's say we have a set $X$ and a set of $\mathcal{C}$ of subsets of $X$, which we think of as conditions that we do not want to hold.  For any $S \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ let $f_{\geq}(S)$ be the number of elements $x \in X$ that satisfy all the conditions of $S$, and let $f_=(S)$ be the number of $x \in X$ for which *exactly* the conditions in $S$ hold - that is, the conditions of $S$ hold but the conditions of $\mathcal{C} \backslash S$ do not hold.  From this definition, we get the relation

$$f_\geq(S) = \sum_{T \supseteq S} f_=(T).$$

The inclusion-exclusion principle then says that we can invert this relation.  We have

$$f_=(S) = \sum_{T \supseteq S} (-1)^{|T| - |S|}f_\geq(T). $$  In particular, $$f_=(\emptyset) = \sum_{T} (-1)^{|T|}f_\geq(T)$$ is the number of $x \in X$ that do not satisfy any of the conditions in $\mathcal{C}$.

Möbius inversion is a broad generalization of this idea.  If $P$ is any finite poset then there is a unique function $\mu: P \times P \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, called the Möbius function of $P$, so that if any two functions $f,g$ from $P$ into $\mathbb{Z}$ (or your preferred commutative ring) obey the relation

$$f(v) = \sum_{u \geq v} g(v)$$

then we can invert, getting

$$g(v) = \sum_{u \geq v} \mu(v,u) f(v).$$

Thus in the case where the poset $P$ is the boolean algebra consisting of subsets of a fixed set $X$ with the subset relation, we have $\mu(S,T) = (-1)^{|T|-|S|}$ when $S \subseteq T$.  In the case of the integers with the divisibility relation we get the classical Möbius function from number theory, hence the name.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration and upvote for this nice summary. In fact I regard it as useful hint only.As you mentioned above: "If $P$ is *any* finite poset, we can apply a Möbius inversion on it." The challenge is to find

Comment: (continuing)... The challenge is to find a *proper poset* or a *proper inverse relation pair* which enables us to derive a *combinatorially interesting property* like *at least/exactly* from it. But anyway, posets with Möbius inversions are at least as interesting as starting point as binomial inversion pairs. Best regards, Markus