# Combinatorial proof involving reciprocals

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809894): show that if $n$ is a positive integer then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}\binom{n}{k} =\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\ .$$
I was able to answer the question by an argument involving definite integrals, but I would be interested to see a combinatorial proof.  There is a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437523) by induction, which however IMHO is not a true combinatorial proof as it does not rely on solving a counting problem in two ways.

In a comment on my answer, Jack D'Aurizio pointed to the problem of counting the number of cycles in a permutation.  Picking up on this hint we may try the following.

We write all $n!$ permutations of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ as products of disjoint cycles and count the total number of cycles, including repetitions.  Any particular cycle $(x_1\ \ldots\ x_k)$ occurs once for every permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}-\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$; that is, it occurs $(n-k)!$ times.  There are $P(n,k)/k$ cycles of length $k$, so the answer to the question is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{P(n,k)}{k}(n-k)!=n!(RHS)\ .$$
But I am unable to show that the answer is also $n!(LHS)$.  The alternating signs and binomial coefficients suggest inclusion/exclusion, but I can't make it work.  On the other hand, inclusion/exclusion is normally used to avoid counting repetitions, and here I *do* want to count repetitions, so perhaps I'm completely on the wrong track.

Any ideas?

Comment: does $x(x-1)(x-2)\ldots (x-n+1) = {n \brack n} - {n \brack {n-1} + \ldots \pm {n \brack 1}$ have a inclusion-exclusion interpretation?

Comment: @abel not sure but I will think about it!  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at my answer of the [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809894) which arguments combinatorically based upon permutations of $n+1$ elements with two cycles and the inclusion-exclusion principle. ... And you're right, usually we use the IEP the other way round, namely transform *at least* information to *exactly* information! :-)