# Describe and count the set of sequences containing $20$ or $02$

Tags: combinatorics, automata, formal-languages, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorics-on-words

Let $X = \{ 0,1,2 \}$ be a ternary alphabet and denote by $X^*$ the set of finite sequences (i.e. strings) with three symbols. For $w \in X^*$ with $n$ the length of $w$ and $w = w_1 w_2 \cdots w_n$ denote by 
$$\delta(w) = |\{ i \in \{ 2,\ldots, n \} : w_{i-1}w_i \in \{ 02, 20 \}\}|$$ the number of occurrence of $02$ or $20$ as substrings. For some fixed $n$ and $m$ how could we determine
$$
 \{ w \in X^n : \delta(w) \ge m \}
$$
i.e. the set of length $n$ sequences such that the number of occurrences of $20$ or $02$ is greater than or equal to $m$? Also I am interested in the cardinality of this set, i.e. the number $|\{ w \in X^n : \delta(w) \ge m \}|$.

Comment: Hmm, you can do it in $O(nm)$ arithmetic operations by dynamic programming. Do you need to be faster than that?

Comment: The definition of $\delta(w)$ begins with "For $w\in X^*$...". Shouldn't it say "For $x\in X^n...$"? And strings begin with $w_0$ or $w_1$?

Comment: I am looking for a formula. Strings begin with $w_1$, I corrected the definition.

Comment: I just realized that I assumed from the title that you were interested in the count, but the question actually says that you're interested in the set. Please resolve this discrepancy.

Comment: @joriki: Yes, sorry for the confusion... see my comment in the other thread http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375857/count-the-number-of-strings-containing-ac-or-ca-for-a-fixed-length-over-tern , maybe I should delete the other thread and put both questions in this thread..

Comment: Cool, thanks. No worries.

Comment: Unfornutely I cannot accept both answers...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a theoretical approach. I will slightly change your notation and take the alphabet $A = \{a,b,c\}$. Let us denote by $|u|_{ac}$ (respectively $|u|_{ca}$) the number of occurrences of the factor $ac$ (respectively $ca$) in $u$.
Let $\delta: A^* \to \mathbb{N}$ the function defined by $\delta(u) = |u|_{ac} +|u|_{ca}$.

**Step 1**. Prove that $\delta$ is a sequential function and find a sequential transducer $\mathcal{A}$ that computes it. If I am not mistaken, this is one:
[image]

The vertical bar is a separator and $\delta(u)$ is obtained by adding the outputs when reading the word $u$, starting from the initial state. For instance, if $u = acacabcacacb$, you get 
$$1 \xrightarrow{a \mid 0} 2\xrightarrow{c \mid 1} 3 \xrightarrow{a \mid 1} 2
\xrightarrow{c \mid 1} 3\xrightarrow{a \mid 1} 2\xrightarrow{b \mid 0} 1
\xrightarrow{c \mid 0} 4 \xrightarrow{a \mid 1}5 \xrightarrow{c \mid 1} 4
\xrightarrow{a \mid 1} 5 \xrightarrow{c \mid 1} 4\xrightarrow{b \mid 0} 0$$
and thus $\delta(u) = 8$.

**Step 2**. Let 
$$
L_m = \delta^{-1}(\{m, m+1, \dotsm\}) = \{ u \in A^* \mid \delta(u) \geqslant m \}
$$
Then $L_m$ is a regular language and an automaton accepting this language can be computed by taking the wreath product of $\mathcal{A}$ and of the minimal automaton of the language
$a^ma^*$ on the alphabet $\{a\}$. The resulting automaton has $5 (m+1)$ states.

**Step 3**. (For the first version of your question, which has changed as I was writing this answer). Compute an unambiguous regular expression for $L_m$ (disjoint union,
unambiguous product and unambiguous star) and then replace each letter of $A$ by $t$ to get the rational series 
$s = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |L_m \cap A^n| t^n$. Then use the Taylor expansion of $s$ in $0$ to get the value of $|L_m \cap A^n|$.

Comment: Great answer giving much insight. But Step 3 I did not get, I am not acquainted with the theory of rational series, so could you maybe provide some more details on how to derive a formula for $|L_m \cap A^n|$?

Comment: Step 3 is no longer part of your question (you deleted it), and it requires some work to explain, so I would prefer if you were asking a separate question.

Comment: Okay, yes I was not clear in formulating my question, here I reopened another thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375857/count-the-number-of-strings-containing-ac-or-ca-for-a-fixed-length-over-tern

Comment: I expected a question on rational series, not the same question !

Comment: @J.E.Pin: Okay, sorry for the mess, I edited the question, hoping now everything is clear and separated..

Answer (score 1):

You can get a double sum using [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). I doubt you'll find anything closer to a closed form than that.

Let $C$ be the set of $2(n-1)$ conditions of which we want the sequence to satisfy at least $m$, namely, the $n-1$ conditions that $02$ occurs at a certain position and the $n-1$ conditions that $20$ occurs at a certain position. Let $A_S$ with $S\subseteq C$ denote the set of sequences that satisfy all conditions in $S$. Then we want

$$
\left|\bigcup_{|S|=m}A_S\right|\;,
$$

and by inclusion-exclusion this is

$$
\sum_{\scriptstyle S\subseteq C\atop\scriptstyle|S|\ge m}(-1)^{|S|-m}\binom{|S|-1}{m-1}\left|A_S\right|=\sum_{r=m}^n\sum_{\scriptstyle S\subseteq C\atop\scriptstyle|S|=r}(-1)^{r-m}\binom{r-1}{m-1}\left|A_S\right|\;,
$$

where the right-hand side groups all sets $S$ with a certain number $|S|=r$ of restrictions together. These restrictions may overlap, but if $|A_S|$ is to be non-zero, they must overlap by at most $1$ per pair and be compatible, i.e. we cannot have $02$ and $20$ restrictions at the same position or $02$ and $02$ restrictions at successive positions, but we can have any number of blocks of alternating $02$ and $20$ restrictions. Let $k$ be the number of such blocks. Then $|A_S|=3^{n-r-k}$, since $n-r-k$ elements remain unrestricted. Thus, with $b_{rk}$ the number of ways to arrange $r$ restrictions in $k$ blocks, our sum is

$$
\sum_{r=m}^n\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{r-m}3^{n-r-k}\binom{r-1}{m-1}b_{rk}\;.
$$

To determine $b_{rk}$, note that each block can start with either a $0$ or a $2$, for $2^k$ possibilities; we can distribute the $r$ restrictions over the $k$ blocks in $\binom{r-1}{k-1}$ ways; and we can select positions for the $k$ blocks among $n-r$ positions (of $k$ blocks and $n-r-k$ unrestricted entries) in $\binom{n-r}k$ ways. Putting it all together yields the desired count:

$$
\sum_{r=m}^n\sum_{k=1}^r(-1)^{r-m}2^k3^{n-r-k}\binom{r-1}{k-1}\binom{n-r}k\binom{r-1}{m-1}
$$

(where binomial coefficients $\binom nk$ with $k\gt n$ are defined to be $0$ as usual).

[Here's Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/d59ccf8686bf9542f1c9) that computes this double sum for arbitrary $m,n$.

*P.S.:* Stefan rightly pointed out in the comments that the inclusion-exclusion formula I used isn't the usual one and I should explain why it works.

Fix some sequence $w$. We want it to contribute $0$ to the sum if it fulfils less than $m$ conditions and $1$ otherwise. The first part is easy: If $w$ fulfils less than $m$ conditions, it isn't in any of the $A_S$ that appear in the sum.

So it remains to show that the contributions from $w$ add up to $1$ if it fulfils exactly a set $S'$ of $r'\ge m$ conditions. In this case $w$ contributes $1$ to every $|A_S|$ with $S\subseteq S'$, so the total contribution from $w$ is

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum_{r=m}^n\sum_{\scriptstyle S\subseteq S'\atop\scriptstyle|S|=r}(-1)^{r-m}\binom{r-1}{m-1}\\
&=&
\sum_{r=m}^{r'}(-1)^{r-m}\binom{r-1}{m-1}\binom{r'}r\\
&=&
(-1)^{r'-m}\binom{-1}{m-1-r'}\\
&=&1\;,
\end{eqnarray}

where I used the identity

$$
\sum_k\binom l{m+k}\binom{s+k}n(-1)^k=(-1)^{l+m}\binom{s-m}{n-k}\;,
$$

which is proved on [this very useful page](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/summingBinomialCoefficients.htm) using Vandermonde's convolution. (It's proved for non-negative $l$, $m$ and $s$, so we need to shift the index by $1$ to make the required $s$ non-negative.)

So every $w$ that we want to count contributes $1$ to the sum, which therefore yields the desired count.

*P.P.S.:* Here's a nicer, more combinatorial proof for the inclusion-exclusion formula for at least $m$ conditions (though in a roundabout way the other proof was also combinatorial in that Vandermonde's convolution has a nice combinatorial proof).

Let $l_r$ be the number of pairs $(S,w)$ such that $w$ fulfils all conditions in $S$ and $|S|=r$. That is, we count the number of sequences that fulfil at least $r$ conditions, but once for each set of $r$ conditions they fulfil. Let $e_r$ be the number of sequences that fulfil exactly $r$ conditions, and $d_r$ the number of sequences that fulfil at least $r$ conditions (where each sequence is now only counted once, not once per set of conditions fulfilled). Then

$$
e_i=\sum_{k=i}^n(-1)^{k-i}\binom kil_k\;.
$$

(For some nice insights into this relationship, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/809201).) We want to show that

$$
d_i=\sum_{k=i}^n(-1)^{k-i}\binom {k-1}{i-1}l_k\;.
$$

This fulfils the difference equation $e_i=d_i-d_{i+1}$, so by induction it's correct if it's correct for some $i$, which it is, since $e_n=d_n=l_n$.

(Full disclosure: I changed all the $\binom{r-1}{r-m}$ I had in the original post to $\binom{r-1}{m-1}$ because the proof made me realize that this is the more natural form; of course the two are equivalent.)

Comment: Guess the first formula should read $$ \left| \bigcup_{|S| \ge m} A_S \right|$$ ($\ge$ instead of $=$ in the index)? But staring at them your formulas seem rather mysterious to me... for example if we denote $\{ S : |S| \ge m \} = \{ S_1,\ldots, S_k \}$, i.e. order the sets, then the principle of inclusion-exclusion says $$ \left| \bigcup_{|S| \ge m} A_S \right| = \sum_{ J \subseteq \{ 1,\ldots, k \} , J \ne \emptyset } (-1)^{k+1} \left| \bigcap_{j \in J} A_{S_j} \right| $$ but I cannot relate that to your equations...

Comment: @Stefan: On the first point: You seem to be reading $A_S$ as the set of sequences that satisfy exactly the conditions in $S$ (and no others). It is defined as the set of sequences that satisfy all conditions in $S$ (and possibly also others). Then we don't need $\ge$, since $A_S'\subseteq A_S$ if $S\subseteq S'$. I'm not sure whether your second point will remain open when you take this into account; if it does, feel free to write again.

Comment: Okay, but even if the union is taken over the sets such that $|S| = m$ and I order them $S_1, \ldots, S_k$ and write the formula for inclusion-exclusion as in my previous comment I do not see how to get your formula which looks a little strange to me...

Comment: @Stefan: You're right, I should have explained that formula. I appended an explanation to the answer.

Comment: @Stefan: I added another, nicer proof for the inclusion-exclusion formula. Thanks, by the way; I was always using this formula but never really thought about it properly before you forced me to :-) That cleared things up a bit for me, too.