# Count the number of strings containing $ac$ or $ca$ for a fixed length over ternary alphabet $A = \{a,b,c\}$ using rational series

Tags: combinatorics, formal-languages, combinatorics-on-words

> This question is a continuation the one asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375397/describe-the-set-of-sequences-containing-20-or-02), and which already received good answers. Here I am asking for a solution using rational series of formal languages as suggested by the user J. E. Pin in the other thread.

Denote by $A = \{a, b, c \}$ a ternary alphabet, also denote by $|u|_{ac}$ and $|u|_{ca}$ the number of occurrences of the factor $ac$ and $ca$ in $u$. Define $\delta : A^* \to \mathbb N$ by $\delta(u) = |u|_{ac} + |u|_{ca}$. How could the cardinality of the set of all length $n$ strings such that $\delta(u) \ge m$, i.e.
$$
 | \{ u \in A^n : \delta(u) \ge m \}|
$$
for some fixed $n$ and $m$ determined by using the Theory of Algebraic Combinatorics on Words, i.e. using rational series of languages?

Comment: I fully support @joriki 's comment. When I asked for a separate question, I meant a question on Step 3 for which you asked for details, not the same question.

Comment: Yes, I will edit everything!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Describe the set of sequences containing $20$ or $02$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375397/describe-the-set-of-sequences-containing-20-or-02)

Comment: Okay, now I edited everything hoping to have it clearly separated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most natural rational series approach I know of (the Goulden-Jackson cluster method) gives a rational function $f(s,t)$ such that the coefficient of $s^n t^m$ is the number of ternary sequences of length $n$ having exactly $m$ occurrences of $ac$ or $ca$.  Essentially verbatim from [Noonan and Zeilberger's paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9806036v1.pdf), pp. 10ff, we get
$$\begin{align}
  f(s,t)&=\frac{1}{1-3s +\frac{2 s^2 (1-t)}{1+s - s t}}\\
  &= 1+3 s+s^2 (2 t+7)+s^3 \left(2 t^2+8 t+17\right)+s^4 \left(2 t^3+10 t^2+28
   t+41\right)\\
  &\phantom{=\ }+s^5 \left(2 t^4+12 t^3+42 t^2+88 t+99\right)+\cdots
\end{align}$$